Which weather condition causes the most accidents?
Among all weather conditions (fog, hail, snow, thunderstorms, etc.) which one causes the most accidents?
Note: Ideally I want to limit the question to accidents within general aviation for typical single-engine aircraft like the Cessna 172.

Wind, gusting in particular, accounts for more accidents than all other weather conditions combined.  Temp/humidity/pressure comes second, causing carb icing or high density altitude.  Precipitation (under Ceiling/visibility/precip) is a distant third, mostly about low visibility.  "Convective weather" accounts for just 39 accidents, mostly thunderstorms.
The closest match to "Cessna 172" is "Flight operation type: Personal," shown here.  Removing that filter yields similar ratios.
This is from the NTSB's 2012-2021
General Aviation Accident Dashboard, page 2 of 3.


Something doesn't make sense about the whole graph

@Gabe Can you elaborate please?

Makes perfect sense to me - do you just disagree with the data? Or the categories?

@EndAntisemiticHate The problem with the graph is that the numbers don't add up. There are 7943 "Accidents with Findings" in the leftmost column, which are split in 5 categories: you'd expect those five numbers to add up to 7943, but the first two alone are already over 12 thousand. And the same goes for every other column. I suppose it means that for every accident there is more than one cause, which totally makes sense -  but it does make the graph harder to interpret.

Since there might be several causes, the conclusions drawn in the answers while probably mostly correct, can be a bit imprecise. As an example, what if an accident happens in low light conditions with wind? perhaps low light conditions would have been enough...

Moreover, and this is by far the biggest shortcoming of this analysis, we lack information about the relative probability of all the conditions above. Wind is something that is almost always present, and it follows quite easily that it can be a predominant cause. If one of the categories was "hurricane", with one accident, nobody of course can say that hurricanes are safer than wind - which is not something that OP tries to claim by the way. One could also say (silly example) that in 100% of the accidents the pilot was present and therefore flying without one is better :)

All of that said, I still thing that this gives a pretty good indication of when one should be particularly wary of the situation, and the data is interesting, just to be taken with a grain of salt.

@Gabe in most accidents, there is no single cause, but several causes, which all put together, resulted in the accident. e.g. icing + did not use de-icing = accident. This explains the Category. In Subcategory, it seems some contain others, in particular "Physical environment" also contains "Conditions/weather/phenomena".

@VladimirCravero: Right. The first thing I said to myself on seeing this data was "base-rate fallacy". We can't conclude that windy days are particularly dangerous from this data without knowing how often planes fly in windy conditions.

The question also only asks for what causes the most accidents: that lets us skip past relative probability of the underlying condition. The question doesn't ask what condition, when present, is the most likely to cause an accident. The data does not create a base-rate fallacy. It actually answers the question that was asked. But yes, we should not draw any further conclusions from it.
